# Suggested Google Contacts extensions?

Tags: google-contacts, browser-addons

I wish to start using Google Contacts. Right now, it has almost 1,000 e-mails and it's a mess.

I would love to know of any suggested extensions (online/offline) for Google Contacts that can enhance and ease my transition.

Comment: Why or what would you need a google contacts extension for? Could you think of some specific functionality that the site does not offer?

Comment: Are any of your contacts and emails likely to be duplicates of the same person? If so Contacts has a built-in duplicate checker using the "Find Duplicates" button on the right-hand side of the home screen, or by ticking two or more contacts and selecting Merge These Contacts.

Comment: Simple example - I have contacts in Hebrew, English, and Jibrish.  If there was some way for me to correct the Jibrish ones that would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a service to manage your contacts and feed them into Google Contacts. I use [MemoToo](http://memotoo.com) to manage all of my contacts and to make sure I do not have dups between losts of services including Facebook, LinkedIn and others.

You can read [my post](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/archive/2010/07/07/the-search-for-a-single-point-of-truth.aspx) on how to make sure all your contacts are in sync.